# How do I include this variable in the font.render line?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make the outcome of the dice roll be included in a string of text `blit` to the screen, `"You rolled a" + roll`

I believe the problem is related to the while loop "while running:" or the order in which I have written the code but I have no idea how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. I am new to StackOverflow so I apologize in advance if the title/explanation isn't clear enough.

```py
from random import *
import pygame
import sys

from pygame import rect

"""SETTINGS"""
global roll
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fps = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREY = (200, 200, 200)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

WIDTH = 520
HEIGHT = 500

bg = (255, 255, 255)

"""functions"""


def dice():
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled a ", roll)


"""init"""

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Dice")

"""dice image"""

image = pygame.image.load("diceImage.gif").convert()
image2 = image.get_rect()
imageUsed = pygame.transform.scale(image, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

"""text object"""
surf = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, 60))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 37)
text = font.render("Click the dice to roll a number", True, (30, 128, 190))

surf2 = pygame.Surface((400, 60))
text2 = font.render(("You rolled a", roll), True, (30, 128, 190))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            dice()
            mouse_pos = event.pos
            if image2.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                print('button was pressed at {0}'.format(mouse_pos))

    screen.fill(bg)
    screen.blit(imageUsed, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(surf, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(surf2, (50, 450))
    screen.blit(text, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(text2, (50, 450))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(fps)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lee/Documents/PYTHON/Dice/Dice.py", line 50, in <module>
    text2 = font.render(("You rolled a", roll), True, (30, 128, 190))
NameError: name 'roll' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) at the wrong place. The `global` statement means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals in the current scope.
Declare and init `roll` in global namespace, but use the `global` statement in the function `dice`, to set the variabel `roll` in global namespace:

```py
roll = 1
```

```py
def dice():
    global roll
    roll = randint(1, 6)
    print("You rolled a ", roll)
```

You have to convert the numerical value `roll` to a string by [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) before you can use it in [`render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) and render the text [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html):

```py
text2 = font.render(("You rolled a " + str(roll)), True, (30, 128, 190))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `dice()` function, `roll =` won't actually refer to or modify the top-level `roll` variable, that's where you need the global statement. I'm not sure which IDE you're using, but when pasting the relevant code, mine immediately notifies me that `roll = randint(1, 6)` *Shadows name 'roll' from outer scope*.

I think the `dice()` function should be renamed to something more descriptive, and lose the printing. I'm not knowledgable enough about PyGame to tell if you can get rid of the global variable entirely.

Also, `import *` is generally bad practice.

Comment: The module-level `global roll` does not initialize `roll`. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @martineau Yes, you're right, I don't know what I was thinking of...